# Attempting to create a 2 level drop down select using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I am trying to create a drop down list to display industries, all from a table in MySQL. I want this drop down to influence the second drop down list and reduce the options it gives. Similar to a country and then city selection instead here I am using Industry and then a Specific Industry. I can't seem to get the second drop down list to work as it should.

Drop down code in PHP is below:

```
//retrieves industry table for drop down
function get_industry($connection,$sel){

    $results ="";
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT IndustryID, Industry FROM Industry";

    $industry = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    while ( $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($industry)){

    if ($sel == $rs['IndustryID']){
    $results.=  '<option value="'.$rs['IndustryID'].' " >' .$rs['Industry']. '</option>';
        }
    else {
    $results.=  '<option value="'.$rs['IndustryID'].' " >' .$rs['Industry']. '</option>';
        }   
    }                           
    return $results;

}

//retrieve specific industry tables in drop down

function get_specindustry($connection,$sel){
    $results ="";
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT SpecIndustryID, SpecIndustry FROM SpecIndustry WHERE IndustryID = $_POST [$industry]";

    $specindustry= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    while ( $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($specindustry)){

    if ($sel == $rs['SpecIndustryID']){
    $results.=  '<option value="'.$rs['SpecIndustryID'].' " >' .$rs['SpecIndustry']. '</option>';
    }
    else {
    $results.=  '<option value="'.$rs['SpecIndustryID'].' ">'   .$rs['SpecIndustry']. '</option>';
    }
    }                           
    return $results;

}

    if (isset($_POST['industry'])){
        $selected= $_POST['industry'];
        set ('i',$selected);
        echo get('i');
        }

 if (isset($_POST['specindustry'])){
        $selected= $_POST['specindustry'];
        set ('si',$checked);
        echo get('si');
        }
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<select name = "industry";">    
<option value ="Select Industry"  > Select Industry    </option>
<?php 
   echo get_industry($connection,$sel);
?>
</select>

<select name = "specific industry">
<option value ="Select Specific Industry">Select Specific Industry</option>
<?php 
 echo get_specindustry($connection);
?>
</select>
```

Would be great if someone could help out, can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Thank you.

Comment: PHP is gone once the page loads. You need to send an ajax request...or have the `Select Industry` form submit and the process to a new page with the relevant results.

Comment: I've never used ajax is there any other option? The other thing is my IndustryID is a foreign key within my main table on MySQL.

Comment: There are two options I suggested. 1. AJAX 2. have the form submit and make the second drop down list a separate page. The PHP is on the server so a request needs to be sent to that everytime you want it processed.